# How do I hide empty table cells when display:block on narrow screens?

Tags: joomla3.0, css-tables

On very narrow screens, tables tend to break out of their container, so for screens of 480px or less On my Joomla 3.9x site I have added css like this:

```
td {display: block;}
```

It works fine, except where there are (almost) empty cells. They do contain the `&nbsp;` code which I can't get rid of, so I cant use the :empty selector. Because the cells are now blocked (stacked), the 'empty' cells create a large gap that I don't need or want.

Any ideas, please? Ideally CSS only, but def no jQuery but possibly Javascript if I have to.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I am using JCE Editor and have changed the default 'pad empty cells' from 'yes' to 'no' in Plugin Parameters > Tables. That solved my problem as the :empty selector now works.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `display:hidden` to remove the elements from being rendered.